# Unity не работает аниматор

Tags: unity3d, animator

Разбираюсь в анимации юнити, вот появилась проблема.
Когда я создаю и проигрываю анимацию, ничего не работает, картинка не меняется.
Превиев включал, на ютубе искал, ничего не нашел.
Ниже прикреплен скрин.[image: Скрин окна аниматора]

Кода пока, что нет.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, в чем проблема, почему не проигрывается анимация.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите всё окно с Юнити, покажите инспектор куда прикреплен скрипт